# Powershell how to find the property type of a registry item property

Tags: powershell, registry

I've found several examples showing how to get, set, and create registry keys as well as their properties and values. I need to find what property type a registry key property has (DWord, String, Multistring etc.)

If I do `Get-ItemProperty` I can fetch the values of a property, like so:

```
PS C:\> Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyKey\" -Name MyProperty


MyProperty    : MyValue
PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyKey\
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware
PSChildName   : MyValue
PSDrive       : HKLM
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

However, this does not tell me if the value of MyProperty is a string, a DWord, a multistring, or whatever else it might be. The only way I've found to get that information is to pipe it to `Get-Member`, because the Definition tells me what type it is:

```
PS C:\> Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyKey\" -Name MyProperty | Get-Member
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name            MemberType    Definition
----            ----------    ----------
Equals          Method        bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode     Method        int GetHashCode()
GetType         Method        type GetType()
ToString        Method        string ToString()
PSChildName     NoteProperty  string PSChildName=MyKey
PSDrive         NoteProperty  PSDriveInfo PSDrive=HKLM
PSParentPath    NoteProperty  string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware
PSPath          NoteProperty  string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyKey\
PSProvider      NoteProperty  ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
MyProperty      NoteProperty  string MyProperty=MyValue
```

I can then select the property value, split the string and fetch the first object, like so:

```
PS C:\> ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyKey\" -Name MyProperty | Get-Member | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "MyProperty"}).Definition -split " ")[0]

string
```

I verified that this gives `int` when I do this with a DWord attribute, but this just doesn't feel like the proper way of finding this information. Is there another, more proper or robust way to find what property type a specific registry key property has?

**EDIT:** I also just verified that both String and ExpandString return "string" here so there are edge cases where even the above solution does not work.

Comment: I’m not near a computer to try it myself, but you could give this a go and adapt it to your needs if it works… https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/getting-registry-values-and-value-types

Comment: Oh, yeah that works! That solution looked a bit superfluous for my use case so instead I just do a Get-Item and then directly do .GetValueKind("MyProperty") but the end result is the same. If you want to add it as the correct answer I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the type of a property using the `.GetType()` method:

```sh
$value = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyKey' -Name MyProperty).MyProperty
$value.GetType().Name   # outputs e. g. "String"
```

To explicitly test for a given type, use the `-is` operator:

```sh
$value -is [string]   # outputs True if $value is a string
```

To see how each registry value type maps to a PowerShell type, I've created a registry key that contains values of all possible types and ran the following script:

```sh
$props = Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\test"
$props.PSObject.Properties.Where{ -not $_.Name.StartsWith('PS') }.ForEach{
    [pscustomobject]@{ 'Reg Type' = $_.Name; 'PS Type' = $_.Value.GetType() }
}
```

Output:

```text
Reg Type      PS Type
--------      -------
REG_DWORD     System.Int32
REG_SZ        System.String
REG_QWORD     System.Int64
REG_BINARY    System.Byte[]
REG_MULTI_SZ  System.String[]
REG_EXPAND_SZ System.String
```

As you can see both `REG_SZ` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ` map to `System.String`, so you can't differentiate these when you read them using `Get-ItemProperty`. Instead you would have to use the .NET method [`RegistryKey.GetValueKind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluekind?view=net-6.0):

```sh
$key = Get-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\MyKey'   # $key is of type RegistryKey
$key.GetValue('MyProperty')      # Output the value
$key.GetValueKind('MyProperty')  # Output the registry type of the value
```

This outputs "ExpandString" for registry type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. For other possible values see [`RegistryValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=net-6.0) enum.

Comment: Thanks! The .GetValueKind() suggested by mclayton did the trick better since the return value from that can be used directly in New-ItemProperty for the -PropertyType flag.