# Compare Registry properties; hash compare or simple equality

Tags: powershell, hash, comparison, registry

I am looking to do a hash compare of a variety of things; files, folders, registry properties and registry keys.
File hash is easy...

```
$Hash1 = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath1)))
$Hash2 = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath2)))
if ($Hash1 -eq $Hash2) {}
```

And folder is easy because I can do a get Get-ChildItem, and if the resulting list isn't identical then the compare is false, and if the list is identical then if any individual file hash isn't identical then the compare is false.
However, I am trying to add registry stuff to this, and I am not clear on how to do the `ReadAllBytes()` on a registry property. Or, am I really over thinking this since a property is not a complex file, and I should just first check for property kind with `$sourceKey.GetValueKind($name)` and then compare actual values if the kinds match? Does `-eq` work with every possible data type in the registry? Or are there gotchas I need to worry about?

Comment: I would do registry value comparison as you have outlined. For scalar values you could use `-eq` (case insensitive!) or `-ceq` (case sensitive). Some registry values will be returned as arrays (REG_MULTI_SZ and REG_BINARY), where `-eq` won't work. For these you could use `Compare-Object`.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72374322/7571258